# How to use the Not contain check in the groovy for header valdiation

Tags: groovy, soapui

My requirement is to Validate the Response which should not contain the header which i listed below.

eg.`Header Name :ResponseCheck`

when I use below code I can found the `header` value will be `null`

```
assert messageExchange.getResponseHeaders().get("ResponseCheck","message") == '';
```

but i want to validate that my header itself should not be present in the response in the soap ui.

Comment: Do you want to make sure the header is `null`?

Comment: Nope, i want to the validate the Response Header doesn't contain the any tag with  "ResponsCheck"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use below `Script Assertion`

```
assert null == messageExchange.responseHeaders['ResponseCheck']
```

Comment: Thanks for your Reply Rao

Comment: This is what i have expected, you have solved my issue.thank you